# Invalid character - dollar sign for input param not decoded

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am facing an issue with some SQL scripts where I use parameter passing.

I call a script like this:

```
DEFINE sowner = "SOWNER"
DEFINE auser = "AUSER"
DEFINE tbsp = "TAB"
DEFINE insp = "IND"

@R1/do_your_job.sql $owner $auser $tbsp $insp
```

And inside R1/do_your_job :

```
define sowner = $1
define auser = $2
define tbsp = $3
define insp = $4

alter session set current_schema=$sowner;
```

And I get: Ora 00911: invalid character marking my $ sign

Why is it not decoding $sowner to "SOWNER"?

My file is marked with "set define $" anyway...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `'&variable'` while passing and `'&1', '&2'` etc while reading.

```
DEFINE sowner = "SOWNER"
DEFINE auser = "AUSER"
DEFINE tbsp = "TAB"
DEFINE insp = "IND"

@R1/do_your_job.sql &sowner &auser &tbsp &insp
```

Your `do_your_job.sql` may use it as

```
select '&1','&2','&3','&4' from dual;
```

Result

```
@R1/do_your_job.sql &sowner &auser &tbsp &inspSQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL>
old   1: select '&1','&2','&3','&4' from dual
new   1: select 'SOWNER','AUSER','TAB','IND' from dual

'SOWNE 'AUSE 'TA 'IN
------ ----- --- ---
SOWNER AUSER TAB IND
```

Comment: Thank you!

I figured out, that there was a set define off on the end of my previous script and hence my code seemd to 'forget' the params passed by.

Comment: 'My file is marked with "set define $"' - so using `&` wouldn't work... *8-)

Comment: @Alex Poole : Yes, that's right. I didn't read that line. But,I would say using & is preferable, especially when shell variables use $1.